# Multiple class attributes (from variables) are not displaying in react

Tags: css, reactjs, variables, dom

I am trying to style my react component. But i get for my understanding weird behaviour.

```
<div className={classNames(scss[isOdd ? 'timeline-item-icon-odd' 
: 'timeline-item-icon-even'], [inProgress])}>
```

What i get in the dom is:

```
timeline-item-icon-odd___3K5am progress
```

where progress is from the variable inProgress.

- In my opinion i tought this is the way to do it but apparently it only renders the first class and completely ignoring the second.
- I have set up a single html an css file where i checked my styles before applying and there they all work correctly.

**CSS:**

```
.timeline-item-icon-odd {
      background-color: gray;
      border-color: gray;
}

.progress {
      background-color: green !important;
      border-color: green !important;
}
```

So what i want to achieve is as to have the background according to the variable in inProgress.

I hope somebody has any idea.

Thank you in advance!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Solution:**

```
 <div className={classNames(
            scss[isOdd ? 'timeline-item-icon-odd' : 'timeline-item-icon-even'],
            scss[inProgress]
          )}
          >
```

The solution was the scss in front. So a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add inProgress together with your other conditional css classes you need to add `inProgress` like this:

```
<div className={classNames(scss[isOdd ? 'timeline-item-icon-odd' 
          : 'timeline-item-icon-even',inProgress])}>
```

I hope this would solve the issue. I have tried this and it worked.

Comment: This is exactly the issue i have. It only renders inProgress class like this. `<div class="progress___3ABNv"></div>`

Comment: have you added css loader and scss loader in your webpack ? –

Comment: I was getting the names properly not modified names like yours

Comment: jup this is the version i have: `css-loader": "0.28.3`

Comment: i used create react app feature so i didnt create it manually. can you direct me towards it i only find the package.json in the node_modules/webpack folder